# Retirve Entity Information got exception using session.laod when after session is closed

Tags: hibernate

Iam loading the student object using load method after closing the session iam trying to print the Student name in hibernate 3.0.But i got **LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - the owning Session was closed**.i mentioned the code snipet

```
        Session session=HibernateUtil.currentSession();
    Transaction tx=session.beginTransaction();
    Object o1=session.load(Student.class,new Integer(2));
    tx.commit();
    session.close();
           log.info("Student name"+((Student)o1).getSname());
```

then i added another attribute lazy="true".But same error has thrown.How to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

That's the principle of the `Session.load()` method: it returns a non-initialized proxy to the entity (unless the entity is already loaded in the session). If you want an initialized instance of Student, use `Session.get()`.

Comment: It's useful when you just need a reference to an existing entity, for example to attach it to another one: `Product p = session.load(Product.class, productId); cart.add(p);`